# Accept-Language header is undefined

Tags: node.js, rest, google-chrome, express, header

So the accept language header is undefined, even though in the network tab in chrome it shows that it's sent up.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/
```

Headers...

```
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
```

But

```
export function login(req, res) {

    console.log( req.headers["Accept-Language"] );
```

Prints undefined

```
import {login} from './login-routes';
app.get('/loadAppAndLogin', login);
```

I am not really sure why or what to do

Answer (score 4):

All [incoming header names are lowercased](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_message_headers) in node for consistency:

```
console.log(req.headers['accept-language']);
```

Comment: Awesome! Even when I do that, though, it only shows up sometimes.